# Results from database in separate divs

Tags: php, html

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `15players` WHERE `ClubId`=' . $_GET['ClubId'] . ' ORDER BY `Rating` DESC LIMIT 0, 45 ');
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $playeravatar = $row['baseId'];
        echo "<img class='face16' src=http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/".$playeravatar."-large.png>";
    }
```

I use this code to get results out of my database, but I want all the results to show in seperate divs. They now display like this:

```
<div id='player'>
    ALL RESULTS
</div>
```

but I want them to show up like this:

```
<div id='player'>
    result 1
</div>
<div id='player'>
    result 2
</div>
```

Is there anyone who could help me?

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: The IDs are unique every player has an unique 'baseId' @A.Wolff

Comment: I see as your expected result `<div id='player'>` twice. But why don't you echoed: `echo "<div id="player.$playeravatar"><img class='face16' src=http://packarmy.nl/packs/playeravatars/".$playeravatar."-large.png></div>";`. Something like that  I'm not a PHP guy but should give you the idea what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very very clear for me. this is how i understand your question, u can do like this..

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `15players` WHERE `ClubId`=' . $_GET['ClubId'] . ' ORDER BY `Rating` DESC LIMIT 0, 45 ');
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $playeravatar = $row['baseId'];
        echo "<div class='clsno".$row."'>Your result Result(<img class='whatever _u_want' src='ur_image_link'>)</div>";
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. But the results are now under each other, not next to each other.. Can you help me with that to?

Comment: can u explain me in more detail